# Insert statement using sparql query not working

Tags: insert, sparql, graphdb, sparqlwrapper

I am trying to insert the statement into graphdb using sparqlwrapper but it says query is badly formed, what am I doing wrong ?. I couln't able to figure it out

```
    from SPARQLWrapper import SPARQLWrapper, POST, DIGEST
    sparql = SPARQLWrapper("http://localhost:7200/repositories/repo")
    sparql.setHTTPAuth(DIGEST)
    # sparql.setCredentials("login", "password")
    sparql.setMethod(POST)
    sparql.setQuery("""

    PREFIX ex : <http://example.com/>
    INSERT  { ?system ex:has_canonical_formula ex:C2H8NPbI3. } 

    WHERE { ?system ex:has_formula ex:C2H8NPbI3. }

    """)
    results = sparql.query()
```

Comment: does it maybe work with a dedicated URL for the Update, i.e. `"http://localhost:7200/repositories/repo/update"` - shouldn't be necessary in general, but who knows

Comment: bad syntax: `PREFIX ex : <http://example.com/>` -- there is a space after `ex`.  Online validator: http://www.sparql.org/update-validator.html

Comment: The endpoint for updates is /repositories/repo/statements